# Position element in the middle of the screen after scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

My page is 2x the height of the screen (size varies depending on other item on the page). I want to show an absolutely positioned SPAN in the middle of the screen regardless of scroll position.

I apply the following style on button click, however if I scroll all the way down, the element shows up at the very top of the page since it counts the 50% from the top of the entire page.

```
.Centered {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 45%;
}
```

How do I position the element in the middle of the page based on the scroll potion at the time of a button click?

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want [fixed positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp)?

Absolute positioning positions an item within the context of a page, so it will
scroll up and down with the page.  Fixed positioning positions an item within the context of the viewport, so it does not move with the page.  Instead, it stays in the same position no matter how you scroll.

```
.Centered
{
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:45%;
}
```

The menu [on this page](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus) is a good example of fixed positioning.

Comment: How the heck does this **center** anything?

Comment: Timwi: well, I don't have the HTML roman m was applying it to, but the `top:50%` will move the `.Centered` element halfway down the page, and the `left:45%` will move it most of the way towards the horizontal middle.  So a thin element that is about 10% of the page width wide will appear centered.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Centered 
{
    position:absolute;   
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-height: -200px;
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

This way the trick becomes finding a suitable value for max-height.

Comment: the height will vary depending on the number of items in the grid that's on the page

Comment: @rm then you have to set max-height dynamically via javascript after the grid is filled up with data

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [jQuery Center Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/elementcenter).

Comment: it doesn't even work in [his demo](http://www.alexandremagno.net/jquery/plugins/center/)

Comment: Nothing works in his demo. There is nothing that is **centered**.